# AP Newspaper Membership Records

Tags: data-request, media

Any data on historical AP (associated press) newspaper membership records (from founding to today)?

Comment: I take it ap.org itself doesn't have this information?

Comment: Not anything that I saw on its website.

Comment: Right, but did you email them and ask?

Comment: [Open ICPSR](https://www.openicpsr.org/) has two datasets that may contain some helpful data:  
[Circulation of US Daily Newspapers, 1924, Audit Bureau of Circulations](https://www.openicpsr.org/openicpsr/project/100007/version/V4/view)  
[US Historical Newspapers Readership Surveys, 1929-1970](https://www.openicpsr.org/openicpsr/project/100002/version/V2/view?path=%2fopenicpsr%2f100002%2ffcr%3aversions%2fV2)